# Oracle PL/SQL dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, parameters

I want to save some parameterized sql statements in a table. 
For example:

```
select * from table_xy where table_xy.col = :par1;
```

Is it possible in `Oracle` to detect/fetch the paramteres from an parameterized sql statement with its name.
So when I try to parse the previous sql statement I like to detect all needed parameters with their names (`:par1`) to select the values for the parameters by name (`:par1`) from an other table.

I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please show us some DB Schema and what have you try

Comment: If this is just an exercise to learn PL/SQL then enjoy. If it's for production code I'd recommend not doing this. Concentrate on your business logic, not a "framework" that stores the SQL statements in a table. If you implement this I'll bet you a quarter you'll spend more time working around it than working with it. If you must have queries in the database there's already a place for them: packages, stored procs, and functions.

Comment: I think that is very hard, perhaps you can parse the SQL with `DBMS_SQL` package and analyze there - but definitely not a job for a PL/SQL beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You may use regexp for this

```
SELECT regexp_substr('select * from table_xy where table_xy.col = :par1;','[:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+') FROM dual;
```

If several parameters, use 3-d parameter of regexp_substr

```
SELECT regexp_substr('select * from table_xy where table_xy.col = :par1 and table_xy.col2 = :long_par_name2;','[:][a-zA-Z0-9_]+',1,2) FROM dual;
```

Comment: This won't handle parentheses, operators, and commas (for an `IN` list). There may be other characters; those are just the first to come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with @Ed Gibbs. If you still insist you want this, you might be able to do this more robust the other way around, i.e. when you know the complete list of all possible parameters, you could do a simple search and replace:

```
for r in (
  select parameter, value
  from parameter_table
)
loop
  l_query := replace(l_query, ':'||r.parameter, r.value);
end loop;
```

Please note that this doesn't handle quoted string/unquoted numbers, so you should store all parameter values in a format that can be inserted as-is into the query.